Django IntegrityError: Unique Constraint Violation
I'm working on a Django project using Django Rest Framework (DRF) and PostgreSQL, with a Scan model that tracks different phases of a label scan. I've set a unique constraint on the combination of label_id and phase fields to prevent duplicate scans for the same label in the same phase.
Here’s my Scan model:
class Scan(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("accounts.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label = models.ForeignKey("labels.Label", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phase = models.IntegerField(
        choices=ScanPhaseChoice.choices,
        default=ScanPhaseChoice.unknown.value,
    )
    distribution = models.ForeignKey("factories.Distribution", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store = models.ForeignKey("factories.Store", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["label", "phase"]

When I try to create a new scan, I get this error:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "labels_scan_label_id_phase_81ec6788_uniq"
DETAIL: Key (label_id, phase)=(413, 1) already exists.

I’ve verified that the combination of label_id and phase already exists in the database, but I’m not sure why this error is raised when I've used full_clean() to validate data in the save() method.
What I’ve Tried

Ensuring the constraint is defined in both the database and the model’s Meta class.
Adding validate_unique in the clean and save methods, but it didn’t prevent the error.
Using full_clean() in the save method, expecting it to check for unique constraints.

Questions

Why doesn't full_clean() catch the unique constraint violation in the save() method? I thought full_clean() would validate uniqueness, but it seems this isn't happening here.
Is there a best practice for handling unique constraint violations in Django when using DRF and PostgreSQL for cases where a combination may exist already?
Should I check for duplicates manually in the save() method, or is there a more efficient way to prevent this error?

Any insights on why this is happening and suggestions for how to handle it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Well as the error says, you already have an entry with label_id=413 and phase_id=1, so you can not add a second one.

Can you show how you are checking and inserting this, this might be useful to diagnose the problem.

Thanks, @willeM_VanOnsem!
I'm using full_clean() in the model's save method, which I expected would check validate_unique. However, it seems full_clean() only validates fields locally and doesn’t query the database for uniqueness. So the database ends up raising the IntegrityError instead.

Can you share the version you are using? Because not all versions check unique_together (which is more or less deprecated anyway).

I'm using Django 4.2.16 @willeM_VanOnsem

I noticed that when I try adding a duplicate entry through a regular request, Django correctly raises a 400 Bad Request with the message: "The fields label, phase must make a unique set." However, at random, some requests still result in an IntegrityError instead of a 400 response.

the "random" part is a bit worrying. Are you sure it is not just one viewset/api view/... that does this?

I have only one viewset. When I submit through the admin panel or manually (with postman) , there is no issue. However, when the frontend sends labels consecutively, sometimes one of them causes this issue. But under normal circumstances, it works fine.
The question is why when the front sends the same label several times, sometimes it works correctly and sometimes it gives an error @willeM_VanOnsem

Might be a race conditions: Django checks uniqness, but if you thus submit two records almost simultaneously, they might both check uniqness, see that the combination is "still available", and then both try to record it.

Yes, I think it might be a race condition. Do you have any suggestions on how I could fix it? @willeM_VanOnsem

Lokcing the table, but this will thus decrease throughput.
